# Why i am getting Validation error even when input is correct in form

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, backend

I was learning Django form validation from some online resource , was working on form validation , I created  a validation error depicting the condition and passed it in form field , **but the validation error is raising even if I am giving correct input**. Similar to this  happened when i raised a validation error for botcatcher without using validators, the error was not raised even i was giving input through inspect (its code is commented)  ,Do help me out!

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators


def check_name(value):
    if value[0].lower() != 'K':
        raise forms.ValidationError('Name  should start with K')


class FormName(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(validators=[check_name])
    email = forms.EmailField()
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    botcatcher = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                 widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                                 validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])
    # def cleaned_botcatcher(self):
    #     botcatcher = self.cleaned_data['botcatcher']
    #     if len(botcatcher) > 0:
    #         raise forms.ValidationError('CAUGHT THE BOT')
    #     return botcatcher
[webpage for same][1]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms
# we can also use from basicapp import forms . refers to current directory
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basicapp/index.html')


def form_name_view(request):
    form = forms.FormName()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.FormName(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # DO something
            print("VALIDATION SUCCESS , POSTED")
            # Retreiving posted data
            print("NAME: " + form.cleaned_data["name"])
            print("EMAIL: " + form.cleaned_data["email"])
            print("TEXT: " + form.cleaned_data["text"])

    return render(request, 'basicapp/form_page.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that if in the ```name``` field, you enter  ```Karen```, it will raise an error?  Please include some debugging results.

Comment: its solved now , there was a tiny mistake i  used lower function but was checking  with upper case character thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake in check_name validator function there i have used lower but i am checking with upper  case 'K' which is leading to unmatching.

```
def check_name(value):
    if value[0].lower() != 'k':
        raise forms.ValidationError('Name should start with k')
```

But still i need help regarding the botcatcher validator that was not raising the error , even when it should.